# How to modify python dist-packages used by mod_wsgi

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi, httpd.conf

I installed apache and `mod_wsgi` module to deploy a `django` application.

I have anaconda as python distribution in my machine, so I installed mod_wsg this way:

```
$ ./configure --with-apxs=/usr/local/apache2/bin/apxs \
--with-python=ANACONDA_PATH/bin/python
$ make
$ make install
```

So, I indicated to `mod_wsgi` to use the python of anaconda.

Then, I added the module `mod_wsgi` to the `httpd.conf` of apache2.

I added this to `000-default.conf`

```sh
    Alias /static PATH_TO_MY_PROJECT/MYPROJECT/static
    <Directory PATH_TO_MY_PROJECT/MYPROJECT/static>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory PATH_TO_MY_PROJECT/MYPROJECT/MYPROJECT/>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>
    WSGIScriptAlias / PATH_TO_MY_PROJECT/MYPROJECT/MYPROJECT/wsgi.py
```

I restarted apache, but when I tried to run localhost on browser, I get this error logs.

```sh
[Tue Jan 26 18:35:47.983537 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 15034:tid 140139653007104] [client ::1:56161] mod_wsgi (pid=15034): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/PATH_TO_MY_PROJECT//MY_PROJECT//wsgi.py'.
[Tue Jan 26 18:35:47.983685 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 15034:tid 140139644614400] [client ::1:56162] mod_wsgi (pid=15034): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/PATH_TO_MY_PROJECT//MY_PROJECT//wsgi.py'.
[Tue Jan 26 18:35:47.983706 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 15034:tid 140139653007104] [client ::1:56161] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Tue Jan 26 18:35:47.983725 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 15034:tid 140139644614400] [client ::1:56162] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Tue Jan 26 18:35:47.983746 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 15034:tid 140139653007104] [client ::1:56161]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 187, in __call__
[Tue Jan 26 18:35:47.983767 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 15034:tid 140139644614400] [client ::1:56162]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 187, in __call__
[Tue Jan 26 18:35:48.001509 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 15034:tid 140139644614400] [client ::1:56162]     self.load_middleware()
[Tue Jan 26 18:35:48.001556 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 15034:tid 140139644614400] [client ::1:56162]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 45, in load_middleware
[Tue Jan 26 18:35:48.013186 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 15034:tid 140139644614400] [client ::1:56162]     mw_class = import_by_path(middleware_path)
[Tue Jan 26 18:35:48.013231 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 15034:tid 140139644614400] [client ::1:56162]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 31, in import_by_path
[Tue Jan 26 18:35:48.013291 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 15034:tid 140139653007104] [client ::1:56161]     self.load_middleware()
[Tue Jan 26 18:35:48.013332 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 15034:tid 140139653007104] [client ::1:56161]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 45, in load_middleware
[Tue Jan 26 18:35:48.013356 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 15034:tid 140139653007104] [client ::1:56161]     mw_class = import_by_path(middleware_path)
[Tue Jan 26 18:35:48.013381 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 15034:tid 140139653007104] [client ::1:56161]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 31, in import_by_path
[Tue Jan 26 18:35:48.026342 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 15034:tid 140139653007104] [client ::1:56161]     error_prefix, module_path, class_name))
[Tue Jan 26 18:35:48.026630 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 15034:tid 140139653007104] [client ::1:56161] ImproperlyConfigured: Module "django.contrib.auth.middleware" does not define a "SessionAuthenticationMiddleware" attribute/class
[Tue Jan 26 18:35:48.037857 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 15034:tid 140139644614400] [client ::1:56162]     error_prefix, module_path, class_name))
[Tue Jan 26 18:35:48.037903 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 15034:tid 140139644614400] [client ::1:56162] ImproperlyConfigured: Module "django.contrib.auth.middleware" does not define a "SessionAuthenticationMiddleware" attribute/class
```

The problem here is that, `mod_wsgi` points to `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` and I need that it point to sites-packages of anaconda as I specified in the mod_wsgi installation.

Any help? I will answer to extra questions with pleasure.